How to specify User's IdentityID when configuring IdentityPool's Authenticated IAM Role
Consider the following:

An AWS Cognito Identity Pool (Identity Pool ID: us-east-1:abc)
A User that exists in the above pool  (Identity ID: us-east-1:xyz)
An AWS IoT Core Policy (or any AWS resource)

I want the Cognito Users to be able to run
aws iot attach-policy --policy-name <policy-name> --target us-east-1:xyz

But ONLY ON this particular Identity Pool (this is fine, we have the ARN),
AND on their OWN "Identity Id", i.e us-east-1:xyz.
I want to set up the Authenticated Role for this Identity Pool such that when Users (after they get AWS Creds) attempt to do this action(iot:AttachPolicy) it's only permitted on their own Identity ID.
For example:
- Effect: Allow
  Action: 
    - iot:AttachPolicy
  Resource:
    - "${Some Placeholder that resolves to (Principal) User's Identity ID}"
    - !GetAtt IoTCorePolicy.Arn

NOTE:

A Cognito User's Identity ID IS NOT THE SAME as its UserPool Sub value.
Part of the issue is that Identity Id DOES NOT follow the ARN format.

I am new to Identity Pools and am not finding the documentation relevant to my use case.
If you have any idea please let me know.
